# When can we use the implies arrow?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

So I'm a complete beginner to logic and set theory and I've been trying to learn a bit about conditional statements and logic however I'm quite confused on if then statements.
For example if $p\implies q$
I saw that this means that if p is true then q must be true also
My confusion is when can we use this arrow can we only use it if the statement is true?

As an example if I had the statement if $x^2>0
$ then $x<0$ could I write $p\implies q$ where p=$x^2>0
$ and $q=
 x<0$

Or would it be incorrect to do so as this statement is false if this is not true when we see the implies arrow in theorems and proofs how am I to know that the statement is true or false?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use it when it's false. I mean, you are not breaking any rule with that, but the main issue with $p \Longrightarrow q$ is that when $p$ is false, you have no power to decide what will happen with $q$. For example, "If $p$ is divisible by 4, then $p$ is an even number". What will happen if $p$ is not divisible by 4? Well, it can be 5 (so its odd), but it also can be 6 (even).

Comment: Let $P$ represent the statement that $(2 + 2) = 5$ and let $Q$ represent the statement that $(2+2) = 6$.  Then the statement $\{P \implies Q\}$ is a **true** statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p\implies q$ is considered to have a value of $true$ in one of these two cases

- $p$ is false

or

- $p$ is true and $q$ is true

So e.g. if one says this statement:

*if the Earth is larger than the Sun, then 5 is even*

this statement is **true** even though both $p$ and $q$ are false here.

But if one says:

*if the Sun is larger than the Earth, then 5 is even*

this statement is false.

Now to your question. You should write

$p\implies q$

when the implication as a whole is $true$
i.e. in one of the two cases mentioned above.

By the way before studying first-order logic it might be better to learn propositional logic.

Comment: So basically the implies arrow always indicates a true statement when seen in textbook proofs?

Comment: Right. Another way to read it is: "if p is true" THEN "q is necessarily also true" And... also if "p is false" THEN "I don't know what q is - true or false". So basically the implication is not worth much if p is false.

Answer (score 0):

p -> q
if p then q means that if p is true then q has to be true.
in your example x < 0 doesn't necessarily be true if x^2 > 0